# how to reduce a list of 16 elements to 8 elements by joining 2 elements in the initial list together

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

`lst1=['ff','55','00' ,'90', '00' ,'92', '00' ,'ad' ,'00', 'c6', '00', 'b7', '00', '8d', '00' ,'98']`

I would like to join each 2 elements in the list together to obtain a new reduced

`list2=[ff55, 0099, 0092, 00ad, 00c6,00b7,008d,0098]`
any idea write it down.
Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking us to code for the OP, the OP needs to show what they've tried and how they would approach the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
lst1=['ff','55','00' ,'90', '00' ,'92', '00' ,'ad' ,'00', 'c6', '00', 'b7', '00', '8d', '00' ,'98']
lst2=[]

for i in range(len(lst1)/2):
    lst2.append(lst1.pop(0)+lst1.pop(0))
print(lst2)
```

**Output:**
['ff55', '0090', '0092', '00ad', '00c6', '00b7', '008d', '0098']

Answer (score 1):

## Diclaimer

I did it just out of curiosity, and than decided that since I've already spent my time on it, I would post it. I still support the point that OP should have invested more effort into this, and I've voted to close the question.

---

Anyway:

```
list(map(lambda x: x[0]+x[1], zip(a[::2], a[1::2])))
```

`a[::2]` is [list slicing syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation). `a[::2]` means "take every second element starting from first", `a[1::2]` means "take every second element starting from second"

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) zips two sequences together:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> list(zip(a,b))
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

`map` applies function to every item in an interable

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> list(map(lambda x: x+1, a))
[2, 3, 4]
```

`lambda` is python [lambda notation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda). It's a shortcut to create anonymous function.

Comment: If the list length is not even, there will be an exception.

Comment: @Taha sure, but such case is clearly outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @Taha on second thought, zip takes the number of elements equal to the number of elements in shortest iterable, so in case of odd list length the last element would jsut be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

to improve on the answer of Yash:

Here is a inplace solution:

```
lst1=['ff 55 00 90 00 92 00 ad 00 c6 00 b7 00 8d 00 98']

for i in range(len(lst1)/2):
    lst1.insert(i, lst1.pop(i)+lst1.pop(i))

print(lst1)
```

Output: ['ff55', '0090', '0092', '00ad', '00c6', '00b7', '008d', '0098']

This way there is no need for the second list... of course this depends on your application